# How do i use wordpress navigational menus in salesforce communites site using CMS Connect? Running into CORS and CSP issues

Tags: community, cors, csp, wordpress

[image]Hey Everyone! I want to use the nav menu from or wordpress site on our salesforce communities based help center using Salesforce CMS connect. But, I am running into some issues that the wider internet has not been able to provide an answer for. The problem manifests as so and raises some issues mentioned below in the console:[image: header issue]

I have added paths and URL's to CMS connect as well as the urls to CSP Trusted Sites and CORS in SF:

But am still receiving several error messages:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://ike2021stage.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/ike2021/css/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' blob:
```

And

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ike2021stage.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/ike2021/js' from origin 'https://ikegps--livepreview.um2.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Note here, I have attempted to add the Access-control-allow-origin header in the header.php file in WordPress, but no luck so far. Im thinking I may need to add it elsewhere/differently.

Can anyone help or tell me where I am going wrong? Much appreciated.